# Moving forward and backward between images files

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-2.7, pygame

Trying to make a simple image gallery where I can flip through a group of images
I got far enough to load each image by a single keystroke.
how can I tell python to flip through a group of images with arrows as in an image gallery

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE)

WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT = 768

# --- main ---

# - init -

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 
pygame.NOFRAME)
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')

# - objects -   

penguin = pygame.image.load("download.png").convert()
mickey = pygame.image.load("mickey.jpg").convert()

x = 0 # x coordnate of image
y = 0 # y coordinate of image

# - mainloop - 

running = True

while running: # loop listening for end of game
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                #screen.fill( (0, 0, 0) )
                screen.blit(mickey,(x,y))
                pygame.display.update()
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                #screen.fill( (0, 0, 0) )
                screen.blit(penguin,(x,y))
                pygame.display.update()

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the images into a list and then just increment an index variable, use it to get the next image in the list and assign it to a variable (`image`) which you blit each frame.

```
import pygame


WIDTH = 1366
HEIGHT = 768

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pygame.NOFRAME)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # Needed to limit the frame rate.
pygame.display.set_caption('Katso')
# Put the images into a list.
images = [
    pygame.image.load('download.png').convert(),
    pygame.image.load('mickey.jpg').convert(),
    ]
image_index = 0
image = images[image_index]  # The current image.

x = 0  # x coordnate of image
y = 0  # y coordinate of image

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                image_index -= 1  # Decrement the index.
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                image_index += 1  # Increment the index.

            # Keep the index in the valid range.
            image_index %= len(images)
            # Switch the image.
            image = images[image_index]

    screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
    # Blit the current image.
    screen.blit(image, (x, y))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)  # Limit the frame rate to 30 fps.

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: thank you so much, would i be greedy to ask if i can make two lists each called by a number key?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You can create as many lists as you want (only limited by the memory of your computer).

Comment: I was planning for 5 lists and each list should be called by a keystroke number 1 to 5

Comment: Do you want to display five different images at the same time (one for each list) or only one image and switch between the different lists? Maybe it would be better to ask a new question and add some code to show us what you've tried, so that we can better understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Just one image at a time and switching between different lists.
Thank you so much

Comment: Then I'd just assign the currently selected list to the `images` variable. For example when the user presses '3': `if event.key == pygame.K_3: images = images3`. And update the index and the current image afterwards.